# Why is JavaScript blocking the ui update (via jquery) here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

In this code, why does the css change not complete until the while loop finishes? I know a loop hangs the browser but I would have thought the css change would be synchronous and therefore finish before the while loop even starts.

Bonus Question: Is there any way for me to get that css change to complete before moving to the while loop without giving up control of the javascript thread?

```
function run() {
    var then = +new Date()
        , now
        ;

    $('#mydiv').css('display','block');

    now = + new Date();
    while (now - then < 5000) {
        now = +new Date();
    }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezVZT/2/

Comment: The browser redraws on its own. There isn't a way to force a redraw with JavaScript.

Comment: The real question is why are you wasting 5 seconds in a delay loop when there are better ways to delay execution?

Comment: "*[...] without giving up control of the javascript thread?*" No. The thread has to have idle time to work on the UI redraw.

Comment: the 5s loop is just for the example. in my real life problem, i want to make a ui change and then continue to do other work. I don't want that other work to block the ui change, but I also can't use a setTimeout or anything similar because I cannot release the javascript thread (don't ask).

Comment: @csturtz If there are special conditions attached to your question then add them to the question. If you don't explain the problem clearly then you won't get a proper answer. In this case, if you're forcing the browser to keep running Javascript then your page updates will suffer. Javascript is a single-threaded system: you can't do two things at once.

Comment: Have you considered using a WebWorker to do whatever this important work is? That will give you a second (and third, fourth,...) thread.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sounds like my only choice is to release the thread and hope for the best. unfortunately, in this environment, it's anyone's guess as to when I'll get the thread back. @MikeW I can't use a WebWorker as this environment doesn't support them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers don't always update the page immediately. They'll often wait with updates rendered but not painted while scripts execute and batch all the repainting together.

In your code you're applying a change to the styling, but then executing a 5 second loop which will block everything. The CSS change just has to wait.

If you need to wait five seconds before doing something use a setTimeout() call, or since you're using jQuery, look at `.delay()`.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like $elem.addClass('xyz') solve your problem? you can then assign the display: block to your class in css. Maybe that would be faster?

Comment: But the `class` attribute change won't take effect until the browser gets control again so there won't be any visible difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It might work.

```
function run() {
    var then = +new Date()
        , now
        ;

    $('#mydiv').css('display','block');
    $("#mydiv", window.parent.document).load($("mydiv").html());

    now = + new Date();
    while (now - then < 5000) {
        now = +new Date();
    }
}

function reset() {
    $('#mydiv').css('display','none');
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything. it still takes the 5s for the css change to be made

Comment: oh ya..its not working..I have provided alert into loop, so it might blocked the thread execution and displayed the div. But if I remove alert from loop it's taking 5s.